# What's wrong with this thumbnailer?

Tags: nautilus

I want Nautilus to generate thumbnails for my .psd files so I put

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=convert
Exec=convert %i[0] -resize %s %o
MimeType=image/vnd.adobe.photoshop;image/x-psd;
```

in **/usr/share/thumbnailers/photoshop.thumbnailer** but Nautilus is amazing and instead of thumbnails I get

```
(nautilus:15745): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: Unable to create loader for mime type image/vnd.adobe.photoshop: Unrecognized image file format
```

Comment: Same question just to make link between them https://askubuntu.com/questions/671060/thumbnail-creation-in-nautilus-fails

Answer (score -3):

It thinks /.photoshop is a file extension, throwing it off. You need to insert a VALID picture and file extension.

Comment: I don't think so, Nautilus selects thumbnailer by mime-type, not by extension. It even shows **Type: Photoshop Image (image/vnd.adobe.photoshop)** in Properties for *.psd files.