# Thumbnail creation in Nautilus fails

Tags: nautilus, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome, thumbnails

I've tried to create a thumbnailer for Nautilus for PSD files with this configuration in

```
/usr/share/thumbnailers/psd.thumbnailer
```

And the following content:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=convert
Exec=convert %i[0] -flatten -resize %sx%s %o
MimeType=image/vnd.adobe.photoshop;
```

`imagemagick` is installed and I have removed the cache via

```
rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails
```

But when I start Nautilus via command line

```
nautilus -q
nautilus
```

I see this very frustrating message.

```
GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: Unable to create loader for mime type image/vnd.adobe.photoshop: Unrecognized image file format
```

Very irritating, as the mime-type is correct

```
% mimetype cv.psd 
cv.psd: image/vnd.adobe.photoshop
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

please, use this command in thumbnailer

```
Exec=/usr/bin/convert %i -resize %sx%s png:%o
```

Comment: sorry, missed -flatten option )

Comment: you can edit your answer